# Voldemort: Getting voldemort.store.InsufficientOperationalNodesException

Tags: key-value-store, voldemort

We are getting following exception while we are calling voldeMortStoreClient.getAll() method rarely.  It was working fine for couple of days. After that I started getting these exception a very few per day and getting increased day by day. Later on all the connections in that pool where turned invalid and all the requests are getting this exception.

Server Version: 1.10.24 
Cluster size: 1

```
voldemort.store.InsufficientOperationalNodesException: 1 get alls required, but 0 succeeded. Failing nodes : []
at voldemort.store.routed.action.PerformSerialGetAllRequests.execute(PerformSerialGetAllRequests.java:197)
at voldemort.store.routed.Pipeline.execute(Pipeline.java:212)
at voldemort.store.routed.PipelineRoutedStore.getAll(PipelineRoutedStore.java:497)
at voldemort.store.routed.PipelineRoutedStore.getAll(PipelineRoutedStore.java:418)
at voldemort.store.DelegatingStore.getAll(DelegatingStore.java:59)
at voldemort.store.DelegatingStore.getAll(DelegatingStore.java:59)
at voldemort.store.stats.StatTrackingStore.getAll(StatTrackingStore.java:133)
at voldemort.store.serialized.SerializingStore.getAll(SerializingStore.java:122)
at voldemort.store.DelegatingStore.getAll(DelegatingStore.java:59)
at voldemort.store.versioned.InconsistencyResolvingStore.getAll(InconsistencyResolvingStore.java:57)
```

**Server side Configuration:**

**stores.xml:**

```
<stores>
<store>
  <name>test</name>
  <persistence>bdb</persistence>
  <description>test</description>
  <owners>test</owners>
  <routing-strategy>consistent-routing</routing-strategy>
  <routing>client</routing>
  <replication-factor>1</replication-factor>
  <required-reads>1</required-reads>
  <required-writes>1</required-writes>
  <key-serializer>
    <type>string</type>
  </key-serializer>
  <value-serializer>
    <type>string</type>
  </value-serializer>
</store>
</stores>
```

**Server.properties**

```
node.id=0
# configs
admin.enable=true
admin.max.threads=40
bdb.cache.evictln=true
bdb.cache.size=12GB
bdb.checkpoint.interval.bytes=2147483648
bdb.checkpointer.off.batch.writes=true
bdb.cleaner.interval.bytes=15728640
bdb.cleaner.lazy.migration=false
bdb.cleaner.min.file.utilization=0
bdb.cleaner.threads=1
bdb.enable=true
bdb.evict.by.level=true
bdb.expose.space.utilization=true
bdb.lock.nLockTables=94
bdb.minimize.scan.impact=true
bdb.one.env.per.store=true
enable.server.routing=false
enable.verbose.logging=false
http.enable=true
nio.connector.selectors=100
num.scan.permits=2
request.format=vp3
restore.data.timeout.sec=1314000
scheduler.threads=24
slop.frequency.ms=300000
socket.enable=true
storage.configs=voldemort.store.bdb.BdbStorageConfiguration, voldemort.store.readonly.ReadOnlyStorageConfiguration
stream.read.byte.per.sec=209715200
stream.write.byte.per.sec=78643200
```

**cluster.xml**

```
<cluster>
        <name>myprodcluster</name>
        <server>
                <id>0</id>
                <host>192.168.1.10</host>
                <http-port>8081</http-port>
                <socket-port>6666</socket-port>
                <admin-port>7777</admin-port>
                <partitions>0, 1</partitions>
        </server>
</cluster>
```

**Client side configuration:**

```
voldemort.max.per.node.connection=500
voldemort.connection.timedout=5000
voldemort.socket.timedout=10000
voldemort.idle.connection.timedout=10
```

**Spring xml for creating store client**

```
<bean id="config" class="voldemort.client.ClientConfig">
        <constructor-arg>
            <props>
                <prop key="bootstrap_urls">${voldemort.url}</prop>
                <prop key="max_connections">${voldemort.max.per.node.connection}</prop>
                <prop key="connection_timeout_ms">${voldemort.connection.timedout}</prop>
                <prop key="idle_connection_timeout_minutes">${voldemort.idle.connection.timedout}</prop>
                <prop key="socket_timeout_ms">${voldemort.socket.timedout}</prop>
            </props>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>


    <bean id="clientFactory" class="voldemort.client.SocketStoreClientFactory" destroy-method="close">
        <constructor-arg  index="0" ref="config" />
    </bean>


    <bean id="storeClient" factory-bean="clientFactory" factory-method="getStoreClient">
        <constructor-arg value="${voldemort.store.name}" />
    </bean>
```

Can you please help me how we can fix this issue

Thanks,
Anand